# Strage authorization error with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I am having a strange error using cancancan.
If I modify the code of a controller or model, when I refresh the browser, cancancan throws "unauthorized" and send me to the home page. It always occurs with all my controllers-models.

It happens with the "superadmin" role, and in the ability.rb the superadmin can :manage, :all , so I dont understand why give me unauthorized. The behavior which I saw, is that the first time that the page is reloaded after a change, the user loses all permissions. If I reload the page again, the users recovers his permissions.

Any ideas about what is happening ?
Thks!

----- FIXED:

See comments below.

Comment: please attach relevant code

Comment: Did you figure it out? If not please provide code sample. Thanks

Comment: it was a copy/paste mistake. I have two times defined the inititialize method on the ability.rb controller, and that was what make this strange behaviour. 

 def initialize(user)
 def initialize(user)

  code.

 end
 end